# Visual Studio MFC change text in Edit Control while typing/dynamically

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, visual-studio-2019, editcontrol

I am trying to set up a MFC C++ App in Visual Studio 2019 such that modifies the user's text as they are typing.

Current layout is 2 radio buttons,

ID= `rdbOn` (set to Group = `True`, with Value int variable `m_isOn` = `1`)

ID= `rdbOff`, `m_isOn` value would be = `0`

[image: Layout]

and 1 Edit Control,
ID= `txtInputBox`, with Value `CString` variable `m_inputString`

Currently, for testing I can see how it would work for a button on click, it would take something like the following and just `SetDlgItemText` of the result.  But that would be after they have typed, not WHILE they are typing.

```
void Onsomebtnclick()
{
    //convert CString to String of m_inputString
    //do some string manipulation
    //convert back to CString
    //SetDlgItemText(txtInputBox, result)    
}
```

**Update:**
[got `EN_CHANGE` to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Wtqq.png)
I was able to get `EN_CHANGE` working with the flag suggestion from user @GoGoWorx.  However, now I just have a slight problem that the cursor is back to the beginning of the edit control `txtInput`.
I'm reading about using a `CEdit::SetSel` but don't know how to use that directly in my code.  I tried
[CEdit control MFC, placing cursor to end of string after SetWindowText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480873/cedit-control-mfc-placing-cursor-to-end-of-string-after-setwindowtext)

```
someDlg::someFunction()
{
    //some logic stuff to get a result string
    SetDlgItemText(txtInputBox, result);
    //need it to set the cursor to the end
    //I tried these, but it didn't recognize (expression must have class type?)
    //txtInputBox.SetSel(0, -1);
    //txtInputBox.SetSel(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you need to use the `ON_EN_CHANGE` message-map notification (called after the control has been updated due to typing or pasting for example)

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyDialog, CDialog)   
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT_CONTROL, &CMyDialog::OnEnChangeEditControl)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void CMyDialog::OnEnChangeEditControl()
{
   // Copy or call your Onsomebtnclick() here
}
```

I'm not sure what you're using for the numeric identifier for the edit control, since these are typically upper case defines - replace `IDC_EDIT_CONTROL` above with your define (possibly `txtInputBox`, but again, these are normally **upper case**, so I'm not sure).

Also change `CMyDialog` for the name of your dialog class too.

Note that we're using the [`ON_EN_CHANGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change) message-map handler here instead of the `ON_EN_UPDATE`, since the `ON_EN_CHANGE` message is sent *after* the control has been updated, whereas `ON_EN_UPDATE` is called just *before* it's updated.

The message-map handlers are described in the **Remarks** section of the `CEdit` control documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cedit-class?view=msvc-160

Regarding your concern about modifying things as the user types - this should be fine, since every change (keystroke or paste from clipboard, etc.) should trigger this handler to be called, where you can change whatever you need. Just be sure that when you're updating the control, you don't trigger the `ON_EN_CHANGE` again and end up in a recursive 'change' loop.

You might be able to do this with some sort of flag to indicate you're the one updating the control, as opposed to the user, however it's probably better to subclass the `CEdit` control to do what you're wanting. There are a few examples out there of how to do this (it's not as difficult as it might sound), for example:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27376/Avoiding-EN-CHANGE-notifications

Comment: Hello @GoGoWorx, thank you for your guidance.  I began looking into the EN_CHANGE, and also you are right that my Edit Control is txtInputBox.  I am realizing some problems now that I am trying to wrap my head around, and have updated the original post.

Comment: You're on the right track with SetSet() but since you're not really trying to select anything, just move the cursor (caret) to a certain position. This is controlled by selecting the position you want with a select length of 0, so in your case, you may want to get the length of your new text to set the "start" of selection position, then the end of selection will be the same (thus 0 characters selected)   res_len = strlen(result); txtInputBox.SetSel(res_len, res_len);